# Grails GORM problem: Object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The Grails code below throws the following exception when trying to `.save()` the Foo object:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException/
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance - 
save the transient instance before flushing: Bar
```

I guess I'm missing out on some of the GORM semantics in connection with automatically populating domain objects from HTTP params.

My question is simply:

- What is the correct way to populate and save the Foo object, without getting said exception?

Model:

```
class Foo {
  Bar bar
}
```

View:

```
<g:form id="${foo.id}">
  <g:select name="foo.bar.id" from="${Bar.list()}" />
</g:form>
```

Controller:

```
class FooController {
  def fooAction = {
    Foo foo = new Foo(params)
    foo.save()
    [ foo: foo ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 'Bar' only exists in the context of Foo, add the following line to Bar.groovy

```
class Bar {
   static belongsTo = Foo

}
```

If 'Bar' is used in other context, you might use in Foo.groovy

```
class Foo {
  Bar bar
  static mapping = {
    bar cascade:'all-delete-orphan'
  }


}
```